# Last column in nested grid always in new line

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, semantic-ui

Consider [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/8uWGjfh5tmhwovfenfXj?p=preview) code. Why is the last element *Item 5* always in a new line / row? It is supposed to be in the same line as the other items.

Note: Plnkr.co preview maybe needs to be resized to *untoggle* the `stackable`
 class.

```
<div class="ui container">
  <div class="ui centered grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="ui stackable five column grid">
        <div class="column">
          Item 1
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          Item 2
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          Item 3
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          Item 4
        </div>
        <div class="column">
          Item 5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      New Row
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: add a float:left and then it will work.

Comment: There has to be one more  </div>  at the end. Am i wrong ?

Comment: Maybe I missed a div at the end, but it still doesn't work as it is supposed to be..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use `<div class="ui stackable six column grid">`?

Comment: Yeah but that is kinda cheaty... There has to be a reason for this :D

Answer (score 0):

- Remove `grid` class on `<div class="ui centered grid">` (semantic doesn´t play nice when nesting grid class elements).

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/51q0mp0h/4/)

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But then I can't use the "outer" grid, can I?

Comment: hans sorry for the late reply, for this displayed example you wouldn't need to, if you have more code that you wish to share where you would need to use an outter grid, I'd gladly check it. Ideally after the grid you would place the row with columns which is not the case on the outter grid, since you place a row, then a five column grid and then columns.